# Integration of Awstats into Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, logging, awstats

I'm currently working on a RoR project, and stumbled upon a problem.

What I have:

- A RoR 3.1 project running on Nginx on a debian server.

What I want:

- I want to be able to see the web statistics of my website. Statistics like the amount of hits, the source and perfectly ordered per some predefined time interval. Preferably with a few cool graphs, charts tables, whatever.

What I did:

- I looked on the internet for some RoR extensions which supported this, but didn't got very excited with the results. Therefore I looked at tools like 'Webalizer' and 'Awstats'. Finally decided to go with Awstats.

What seems to be the problem:

- Now I can access the main page of Awstats, but once I want to look at other months, it sends a request to *awstats.pl*. This request is (I think) send from Nginx to RoR first. Then RoR looks in its *routes.rb* for the correct route. Then RoR can't find the route, and redirects me to the 404 error.

I would like to know if there is somebody out there who has some experience in these kind of things. Maybe knows how to configure Awstats correctly for RoR, or either knows another good statistics tool for RoR.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

-Ron